# maven checkout from cvs and install into repo

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, cvs

Does anyone know of a way to do this quickly? I have an old cvs repo /w a bunch of jars, tagged, etc. I'm looking to bring them over into maven. So basically

1. checkout from cvs
2. install into local repo as maven artifact

I'm well aware how to do both separately, is there any way to combine the 2 tasks gracefully? A further note, we're talking about a lot of jars + different versions of each jar here...

Answer (score 0):

Write a bash script that calls `mvn deploy:deploy-file` for each file. I had to do something like this recently. The tricky part is parsing the groupId, artifactId and version for each of your jars.  If your jars had a string naming convention, you may be able to infer that from each jar file name. If there was no convention, you'll have to manually deploy each one.

Comment: Yeah that was my first idea, just thought maybe there's a plugin or configuration that automates this. I can use tag as version or group id and artifact id would just be name of the jar...

Comment: Not aware of a plugin that automates this. Good luck!